# My Account reorder link onclick Ajax call controller in magento 2.4

Tags: controllers, ajax, magento2.4, reorder

My Account reorder link onclick Ajax call controller in magento 2.3

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

```
 <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder::class)->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
            <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */
            $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
            ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
            ?>' class="action order">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reorder')) ?></span>
            </a>
 <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: what is  you have tried so far?

Comment: try this - https://redchamps.com/ajax-reorder-magento-2-extension.html